# Webcam pixelated with movement

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, webcam, flash-media-server, live-streaming

I'm using `AS3` to live stream video, but whenever the webcam picks up movement the picture is pixelated. Does anyone know how I can get a better picture?

Here are my camera settings:

```
var bandwidth:int = 50000;
var quality:int = 0;

camera = Camera.getCamera();
camera.setQuality(bandwidth/8, quality);
camera.setMode(232,174,15); 
ns.attachCamera(camera);
addChild(video);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening due to your SetQuality settings, most likely. According to the [Adobe Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setQuality%28%29) for this, Flash will reduce quality as necessary to meet your bandwidth requirements. Due to the fact that your bandwidth setting is below the default (which is 16384; 50000/8 = 6250), Flash is probably automatically reducing the quality of the stream to fit your bandwidth limitations.

Try upping the bandwidth settings, see if that doesn't help you. Alternatively, you could set a minimum quality, but make sure you don't hamstring your feed by setting both to very restrictive values.

Good luck.

Comment: Maybe my calculations are wrong, but isn't `50000/8 = 500Kbps`?  Which I would think would be plenty bandwidth to stream live video.

Comment: How can I tell my camera to only send a max of 500Kbps?

Comment: @zLan - `bandwidth` is measured in bytes per second, not kilobytes. Thus, your throughput is only 6k per second. Try using the default - 16384 bytes, or 16 kilobytes - and see if your quality increases.

Comment: @zLan Edit: (You can always try setting it to a very high value - 16777216, for instance, or 16 megs per second.)

Comment: I changed my equation to `bandwidth*1024/8` where bandwidth I set to `100 (100kbps)` and that fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @zLan No problem. Note that the `bandwidth` argument to `SetQuality` is in bytes, not bits, so you don't need to divide anything by 8. (It took me a little bit to realize what that magic number was for.)

Answer (score 0):

Change your quality from zero to a value closer to 100.

Comment: Really choppy. I think that's because it's not sending all the frames.

Comment: I think messing with your `camera.setQuality()` and finding the right balance is the key. I've never seen really good quality from webcams myself, let us know if you get it looking great or not.